# Simplification of a function to a known result

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Im trying to simplify a function whilst already knowing the result that I need to work towards. The function being:

$$\frac{o-n}{3z} = \frac{n}{2z}$$

The result is:

$$n = \frac{2}{5} o$$

I've been trying all kinds of transformations of this in wolfram alpha to see what I'm going wrong but I just can't seem to get there. I'm sure that I'm overlooking something very stupid. Any pointers would be very welcome.

Comment: the result looks right, if $$z\ne 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the equation:
$$\frac{o-n}{3z}=\frac{n}{2z}$$
We [cross-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication):
$$2z(o-n)=n(3z)$$
Divide both sides by $z$ (Note that this expression only becomes correct when $z\neq 0$):
$$2(o-n)=3n$$
Expand:
$$2o-2n=3n$$
$$2o=3n+2n$$
$$2o=5n$$
Finally, divide both sides by $5$:
$$\boxed{n=\frac{2}{5}o}$$